# Inheritance Error

Tags: c++, qt

I made the following program, but now i am getting an error. I searched for error almost 3 hours but worthless. I want to discuss the problem with you people.
I am getting the error: expected class-name before '{' token

```
#ifndef ASKDIALOG_H    
#define ASKDIALOG_H  

#include <QDialog>  
#include "umerwindow.h"    

namespace Ui {     
class AskDialog;     
}

class AskDialog : public QDialog, public UmerWindow // HERE IS THE ERROR     
{
 Q_OBJECT     

public:  
explicit AskDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);     
void showdialog();     
~AskDialog();     

private slots:     
 void on_dokbutton_clicked();     

private:     
Ui::AskDialog *ui;     
 };

#endif // ASKDIALOG_H
```

ASK DIALOG .CPP FILE

```
#include "askdialog.h"     
#include "ui_askdialog.h"     

AskDialog::AskDialog(QWidget *parent) :
 QDialog(parent),     
ui(new Ui::AskDialog)     
{
ui->setupUi(this);     
}

AskDialog::~AskDialog()     
{
delete ui;     
}

void AskDialog::on_dokbutton_clicked()     
{
QString data=ui->dline->text();     
showlist(data);     
 }
```

ASK DIALOG .CPP FILE

```
#include "askdialog.h"     
#include "ui_askdialog.h"     

AskDialog::AskDialog(QWidget *parent) :
 QDialog(parent),     
ui(new Ui::AskDialog)     
{
ui->setupUi(this);     
}

AskDialog::~AskDialog()     
{
delete ui;     
}

void AskDialog::on_dokbutton_clicked()     
{
QString data=ui->dline->text(); 
showlist(data);     
 }
```

Ok so this the header file of UmerWindow

```
#ifndef UMERWINDOW_H
#define UMERWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QListWidgetItem>
#include "askdialog.h"

namespace Ui {
class UmerWindow;
}

class UmerWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit UmerWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~UmerWindow();
protected:
    void showlist(QString &);

private slots:
void on_actionAdd_Item_triggered();

private:
    Ui::UmerWindow *ui;
    QListWidgetItem *itm;
    AskDialog *dialog;
};
```

and this is the .cpp file of UmerWIndow

```
#include "umerwindow.h"
#include "ui_umerwindow.h"
#include "askdialog.h"
#include <QListWidgetItem>

UmerWindow::UmerWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::UmerWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    dialog= new AskDialog(this);
}

UmerWindow::~UmerWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void UmerWindow::on_actionAdd_Item_triggered()
{
    dialog->show();
}
void UmerWindow::showlist(QString &data)
{

}
```

What should i do to resolve this problem? Please help.

**PS:**  I also tried without inheritance, then the compiler gives me a weird ***error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'UmerWindow' with no type*** and ***error: expected ';' before '*' token*** when i create an pointer object of UmerWindow in askdialog.h file. Now what should i do?

Comment: What's with all those ' characters?

Comment: Check whether you are missing `;` at the end of class declaration in Umerwindow.h class declaration, and why you are forward declaring `AskDialog`?

Comment: I think what he meant is that, try removing all the single quotes ' and then try compiling..

Comment: look at the error: "expected class-name before '{' token" What's before the {? Is that a class? What namespace is it in?

Comment: No chance of forgetting ; or things like that. All these header files and .cpp fiels were created by qt creater. I am only writing my code and declaring functions in the header file. I think there is a problem with inheritance of UmerWindow

Comment: I don't know Qt and this may be a dumb question but you seem to be referencing 2 classes with similar names, Ui::AskDialog and AskDialog. Is that intentional or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2):

According to you UmerWindow is basically a typical MainWindow that Qt creator makes, and u might be knowing the QMainWindow inherits QObject and same is the case for QDialog.

So, class AskDialog inherits from two QObject subclasses QDialog and UmerWindow. This is not supported!

Comment: OK i got it. But i did try without inheriting, then the compiler gives me a weird error:
ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'UmerWindow' with no type

and 
 error: expected ';' before '*' token
when i create an pointer object of UmerWindow in askdialog.h file.
Now what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a classic Circular reference problem. You've done this in the umerwindow.h file.

```
#include "askdialog.h"
```

The problem is you've done this *before* forward declaring UmerWindow. As such the #include "umerwindow.h" in askdialog.h has no affect (due to #define already created).

Instead of this #include, please just forward declare the class AskDialog in umerwindow.h.

Answer (score 0):

> error: expected class-name before '{' token

From my remote error resolving skills, I feel you are giving wrong class name while inheriting. Check whether the class name is `UmerWindow` or `umerWindow` or `umerwindow` or `Umerwindow`. Compiler is not understanding the identifier `UmerWindow` in your case while inheriting. Go to the header `"umerwindow.h"` and see what exactly is the class name.

Comment: I spelled the class name correctly. It is UmerWindow but i don't know why is this giving me error

Answer (score 0):

It seems the compiler doesn't know the class `UmerWindow`. Have you tried forward-declaring it? Just add the class definition below the include statement:

```
#include "umerwindow.h"    
class UmerWindow;
```

Also if it's a class created by Qt, it might be in the Ui namespace. In that case, try using the full name in the class declaration:

```
class AskDialog : public QDialog, public Ui::UmerWindow
```